# XML, Javascript - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null

Tags: javascript, xml, null

I am trying to create a table taking an HTML table from within a XML file. However, it keeps giving me the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null` even though there definitely is a tag named `<x>` in the XML file. There is probably a glaringly obvious thing that is causing the problem, but this is the first time I have used XML and JS, so I'm not sure what it it is. Does anyone know what the problem is?

JS:

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","media.xml",false);
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("x")[0];
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<library>
    <x>
        <![CDATA[
        <tr>
            <td>First cell</TD>
            <td>Second Cell</td>
            <td>Third cell</td>
        </tr>
        ]]>
    </x>
</library>
```

Comment: `xmlhttp.responseXML` is null. Can't say why. Can you access that URL manually?

Comment: @sabof its is running directly from USB right now. I'll try from a hard drive, maybe that it.

Comment: "`...there definitely is a tag named <tv>`", then reading `<x>`...? Also looks like `tv` would "close" `x` in your XML. Are you sure your AJAX call has been executed at the time you try to read the response?

Comment: @mm865 You mean without a server? Try uploading it to a server.

Comment: @Teemu thats just cause I was generalising my script before posting. Will fix.

Comment: @yarix not sure what you mean by that. It's valid syntax as far as I can tell, and the file is definitely a `.xml` file.

Comment: @sabof I uploaded to a server, got the exact same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse your XML. Without parsing you can't access the nodes in the response string.

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","media.xml",false);
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

parser = new DOMParser(); // new Parser
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlDoc,"text/xml"); // Parse string

document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("x")[0].textContent || xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("x")[0].innerText; // Use textContent for getting the content of the "x" node. In IE you have to use "innerText"
```

[DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

> DOMParser can parse XML or HTML source stored in a string into a DOM
>   Document.

<kbd>[JSfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pisi2012/Xe436/)</kbd>

Comment: XMLHttpRequest has the property responseXML to avoid doing this right? Check out the property definition in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the error, but now a second error is being show that says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined` on the `document.getElement....` line, even though `xmlDoc` is defined.

Comment: Then the element you're searching for doesn't exist. Please, use the browser console for further debugging.

Answer (score -1):

Please check the XML file which you have created. Your code looks good. It is not able to open and read the file properly.

Arun